# Facebook insights page (https://www.facebook.com/insights) is empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I'm trying to claim my website but the link [Facebook insights](https://www.facebook.com/insights) is empty.

[image]

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ and we'll take a look. Make sure to include as much detail as possible: your App ID, your URLs, the error you receive, screenshots etc.